# How can i substract 30 minutes to my timestamp R

Tags: r, timestamp

How can I substract 30 minutes to my TIMESTAMP without loosing the original format?

My format is "%Y%j%H%M".

For example, I want 2020-08-27 06:30:00 to become 2020-08-27 06:00:00.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What is the class of your data? If your data is called `df` check `class(df$column_name)`. If it is of class `POSIXct` you can do :

```
df$new_column <- df$column_name - 30*60
```

Or with `lubridate` :

```
df$new_column <- df$column_name - lubridate::minutes(30)
```

---

If the class is something different than `POSIXct` (eg - character) you need to first change it to `POSIXct` class before using the answer above. That can be done with

```
df$column_name <- as.POSIXct(df$column_name, tz = 'UTC')
```